# Easiest way to deploy docker application

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry

My application uses multiple technologies like redis, couchDB, nodejs, ...
Some of them I take from docker hub (e.g. redis) and some others (e.g. my nodejs app) is hosted in my docker repo on my own server.
Now what is the easiest way to deploy my full application to a remote system?
It would be great if I could just use one docker-compose.yml and run `docker-compsoe up -d`, but I think this won't work, because I use images from my own docker repo. So do I first have to pull all these images via `docker pull` on the remote system or is it possible to tell my .yml-file to pull from my repo? Or is there any other solution?

Comment: You should provide some infos about the target system.

Comment: is this necessary? I thought we use docker because we don't care about the host system? But ok: it's a debian VM, hosted on Azure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't worry about private registry. docker-compose can pull images from private repository automatically.

You need authenticate before on private resgistry before pulling. Type `$docker login <private_repository>` before `$docker-compose up`

**note!** There is need to give a right names for your own images.
You need tag your image with YOUR_REGISTRY_HOST

`docker tag [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG] [REGISTRYHOST/][USERNAME/]NAME[:TAG]`

and after it you can push image to your own registry. into docker-compose you need specify full image name with hostname like

`image: my_registry/image_name`

Comment: Thank you, I will try it! But what if the image in my private registry has the same name like an image from docker hub? Which one will be pulled?

Comment: You need tag your image with YOUR_REGISTRY_HOST 
`docker tag [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG] [REGISTRYHOST/][USERNAME/]NAME[:TAG]`
and after it you can push image to your own registry.

into docker-compose you need specify full image name (with hostname like 
`image: my_registry/image_name`

Answer (score 2):

Bukharov provided the correct steps. For myself, I asked a similar question about that topic for my CI setup. I made a little documentation that I want to share.

- Start a Registry Container

  `run -d -p 127.0.0.1:5000:5000 --restart always -v  registry:/var/lib/registry --name registry -e REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true registry:2.4`
- Prepare your local images for the private registry.

  `docker tag <local image> localhost:5000/<local image>`
- Add an image to the private registry.

  `docker push localhost:5000/<local image>`
- Pull an image from the private registry.

  `docker pull localhost:5000/<local image>`
- Remove a tag from an Image.

  `docker rmi localhost:5000/gdal:1`
- List all images.

  `curl -X GET http://localhost:5000/v2/_catalog`
- List all tags for the listed images.

  `curl -X GET http://localhost:5000/v2/<repository>/tags/list (Auflistung aller Tags zu einem repository)`
- Read all manifest files.

  `curl -X GET http://localhost:5000/v2/<repository>/manifests/<tag oder digest> -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json"`
- Delete an Image in the private registry.

  `apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl jq`

  `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/burnettk/delete-docker-registry-image/master/delete_docker_registry_image.py | tee /usr/local/bin/delete_docker_registry_image >/dev/null chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/delete_docker_registry_image`

  `export REGISTRY_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2`

  `delete_docker_registry_image --image nginx:stable-alpine –dry-run`

  `delete_docker_registry_image --image nginx:stable-alpine`

> For further information to access the private registry across the web:  `https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#/running-a-domain-registry`
> General information about a private docker registry: `https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/`